# How to differentiate this function, is the rest of the solution correct?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Consider $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $\Omega$ open and $f\in\mathcal{C^1(\Omega)}$.

Now we define another function $u:\mathbb{R^3}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $u(x,y,z)=x^4\cdot f(y/x,z/x)$

I'm asked to prove that $x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=4u$

**My try:**

Calculating those partial derivatives by using the product rule, multiplying by the respective variables and adding up, I end up with:

$4x^4f(y/x,z/x)+x^5\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(y/x,z/x)+x^4y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y/x,z/x)+x^4z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(y/x,z/x)$

Since the first term is already $4u$, for the equality to hold, I'd have to prove that:

$x^5\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(y/x,z/x)+x^4y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y/x,z/x)+x^4z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(y/x,z/x)=0$

But I have no idea how to prove such thing, as I don't know how to calculate those partial derivatives, there must be some chain rule to be applied here, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the chain rule for several variables and everything will magically disappear:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\phi(x,y,z),\psi(x,y,z))=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi}\cdot\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\psi}\cdot\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} \quad\text{etc (for $y$ and $z$)}
$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!